# how do i get the facebook friends username in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the only fb username how it is?
This is my code

```
$user = $this->facebook->user();
$fbfriends = $this->facebook->call('get', 'me/friends');
$friends=$fbfriends->data;
```

here it returns the name and id.But the name is not username.is there any solution to get the username only from the above function using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting your username

```
http://graph.facebook.com/id?fields=username
```

and for friends usernames

```
http://graph.facebook.com/id/friends?fields=username&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

For more information [Facebook Graph Api Fields Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$user = $this->facebook->user();
$fbfriends = $this->facebook->call('get', 'me/friends?fields=id,username,name');
$friends=$fbfriends->data;
```

This will fetch the `username`, `id` and the `name` of the user.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/id
```

you will get a json result, including name